# DocumentRoot must be a directory CentOS6.5

Tags: apache, apache2, config, virtualhost

I've been having a problem setting a directory in my virtualhosts, and am wondering if you guys can help. This is for Laravel and I have already made sure that the location exists and SELinux is disabled.

My config is as follows:

http://i.gyazo.com/31cdec5f9d830ec43923b4ccf1588d4c.png

I can't paste it here because the symbols mess up the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your document root to:

```
/var/www/QuickPush/public
```

See the following virtualhost configuration I always use under CentOS 6:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName quickpush.jackryder.co.uk
    DocumentRoot /var/www/QuickPush/public
    <Directory /var/www/QuickPush/public>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f      
            RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
        </IfModule> 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Ignore me, i had an error on a different line which i must have uncommented by accident, your config worked :P